# How to set up some JavaScript into WordPress (API)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api

I have this code, and I cant get it to work in my WordPress, I have used the addons `Insert Headers & Footers` and also `WP Coder`... but I am not sure why it will not work, the page is just blank.

How can I get this to work? What should I place where in the WordPress site - plugins etc.?

I have tried to place this in the "WP CODER" under "HTML code":

But it does not work, the page is blank.

1) Add the following code to the `<head>` section of your website:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"`href=”https://zellr.com/integration/kirpparikalle.css” />

2) Add the following code to the  section of your page. Place it inside the element where you wish to see the login and registration forms.

````
<h1 id="kirpparikalle_title"></h1>
<br/>
<div id="kirpparikalle_container"></div>
<!-- Note: jQuery is requirement for the integration scripts.
If you already have jQuery included in your website, you can remove the next line. -->
<script type="text/javascript" ```src="https://zellr.com/integration/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" ```src=”https://zellr.com/integration/kirpparikalle_i18n.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
KK_COMPANY = ' denlillelandsoldat '; 
KK_CONFIG['redirect_url'] = 'http://denlillelandsoldat.dk/';
KK_LANGUAGE = 'da';
kk_show_default_login();
});
</script>
````

It should show some booking module on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to copy this exact code and paste it where you want it to appear, you have odd characters in the code you've applied on your website. Also the js code might produce an error to made a little change to the wrapper

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://zellr.com/integration/kirpparikalle.css" />
<div id="kirpparikalle_container"></div>
<!-- Note: jQuery is requirement for the integration scripts.
If you already have jQuery included in your website, you can remove the next line. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://zellr.com/integration/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://zellr.com/integration/kirpparikalle_i18n.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(function() {
    KK_COMPANY = ' denlillelandsoldat '; 
    KK_CONFIG['redirect_url'] = 'http://denlillelandsoldat.dk/';
    KK_LANGUAGE = 'da';
    kk_show_default_login();
})( jQuery );
</script>
```

Comment: IT WORKS!!! Thank you so much Ali! :D just saved my day - Cheers Buddy!

Comment: Awesome, happy to help. Please make sure to accept this answer if it's the solution to your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Click the check mark on the left side of this answer, it's below the up vote and down vote icons.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using block editor (gutenberg) or the classic editor?

In classic editor. Paste your codes inside text editor 
[image]

Same concept in gutenberg tho.

Comment: Thanks Romel, i am using the Fusion Builder (Classic Edditor) when i set it in like you describe above, it just shows 3 small icons like a small film with a "play" sign in the middle? what does that mean? the page is then blank if i view it and the footer is gone also.. what did i do wrong?

Comment: If you look at this page i am testing here: http://denlillelandsoldat.dk.prolinux5.curanetserver.dk/api-booking/ footer is gone an no booking fields :(

Comment: make sure you add the link code:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://zellr.com/integration/kirpparikalle.css" />`

Comment: an upvote would be much appreciated. just click the arrow up beneath my answer.